# Session time out in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have used this code in gobal.asa file in classic asp application.

```vbs
<script language="VBScript" runat="Server">
    Sub Session_OnStart
        Session.Timeout = 60
    End Sub
</script>
```

But this is not working for more than 20 mins.

Any one have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the timeout for the IIS webservice instead, that might work.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply But I am using iis8 not find this options

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the "Idle Time-out (minutes)" setting of the application pool associated to your application/site. Once the application pool gets recycled, your session will die.